# Sort JSON object in jq

Tags: json, sorting, key, jq

I have simple JSON object:

```
{
  "dir1/somepath1": 1.2,
  "dir2/somepath2": 3.5,
  "dir2/somepath3": 1.0,
  "dir5/somepath4": 10.1,
  "dir10/somepath5": 30.1
}
```

I want to sort it so it would look like:

```
{
  "dir10/somepath5": 30.1,
  "dir5/somepath4": 10.1,
  "dir2/somepath2": 3.5,
  "dir1/somepath1": 1.2,
  "dir2/somepath3": 1.0  
}
```

**Update:**

I don't understand why I'm getting downvoted

I have proper title, I have proper body and I have proper tag.

Those who know `jq` can answer this question, but I already found the answer. Will wait 2 days and mark the question solved.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could indicate you want a decreasing numerical order.

Comment: java solution can i give or you want in jq?

Comment: only jq, I can sort in ruby )

Comment: Didn't work with jq before, so if I understand sort and sort_by accepts array, but I have an object

Comment: @oguzismail I don't understand what you're getting at?

Comment: @GuillaumeJacquenot I don't understand your comment too, please explain me what I did wrong

Comment: I did not downvote you, but I may guess why question might get downvoted: ordering _objects_ in JSON is a outside of scope of a [JSON spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159): - objects are _unordered collections_ in JSON. i.e. ordering an unordered collection might have a visual/cosmetic effect but has no practical meaning for applications.

Comment: You seem to have asked several questions before but none of them has an accepted answer. People here tend not to post answers to questions asked by people who don't accept answers

Comment: `I don't understand why I'm getting downvoted.` It's generally a good idea to demonstrate how you've attempted to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @oguzismail thanks, I missed it. 

@Dmitry there is tool named `jq`, google it. For me JSON is just output and I want it transform, so I can filter it. 

@peak I've attempted to solve myself at first. What should I put in body? I spent half an hour trying to solve myself and half an hour  searching my problem here. After it I asked the question, what the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question
`jq 'to_entries | sort_by(.value) | reverse | from_entries'`

https://jqplay.org/s/OTbaGREIUH